# OpenGL и многопоточность

Tags: c++, linux, многопоточность, opengl

`g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp -pthread -o main -lglut -lGL` - вот так выглядит скрипт, которым я компилирую свой код.

При запуске программы получаю ошибку

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>     what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted

если компилировать `g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp -pthread -o main -lglut` (есть без параметра `-lGL`), то многопоточность работает, но отрубается OpenGL, разумеется чтобы это скомпилить я закомментил все что связано с opengl. Нужно чтобы одновременно работали и многопоточность и OpenGL.

Код:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

float x=-0.5;
using namespace std;

void renderScene(void) 
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
   glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);
   glVertex3f(0.0,0.5,0.0);
   glVertex3f(0.5,-0.5,0.0);
   glEnd();
   glRotatef(10,0,0,1);
   glutSwapBuffers();
}

void t1()
{
   while(x<1)
   {
      x=x+0.1;
      cout << x << endl;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    thread thr(t1);
    thr.join();

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
    glutCreateWindow("ss");
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: уважаемый, код необходимо приводить в форме текста, а не картинки.

Comment: Непонятно как оно вообще компилировалось у автора.

Answer (score 3):

А если добавить вот эту опцию компиляции `-D_REENTERANT` ?

UPD: Вот так работает, Вы забыли подключить библиотеку `-lpthread`

```
g++ -c ./test.cpp -std=c++0x -pthread -D_REENTERANT
g++ -o ./test ./test.o -lglut -lGL -lm -lpthread -pthread
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.

Comment: @xaja Это автору решать.

Comment: @xaja Это конечно не окончательный и всеобъемлющий ответ (даже до правки), но все же лучше чем никакой. Так что удалять его не надо.

Comment: @KromStern в ответе предложение было (и есть) вопросительным. Это сложно воспринимать как ответ. Больше похоже на что-то среднее между отладкой и угадайкой. После редактирования - да, другое дело.

Comment: @Regent согласен